# How many dice to get one of each of the 6 faces?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

There's this riddle: In a pub the owner is throwing a number of dice simultaneously. "I am trying to get one of each of the six faces", he says, "But it hasn't happened yet". "No", I said "You need at least four more dice to make the odds in favour of such a thing." How many dice does the owner have?

I'm confused because why can we not simply calculate the expected value of the number of times we need to roll a single dice in order to get all 6 values. If this was the case, then we can reduce this problem down to the coupon collectors problem, and see that the expected number of dice is 14.7.

Apparently, for the correct answer, we need to use inclusion/exclusion, and you ultimately get 13 dice.

Therefore, this is my question:

Why can we not use expected value, and why does using expected value get us a different answer?

Comment: The mean and the median are often different for non-symmetric distributions; this is the coupon-collector's problem, but solving for the median

Comment: This makes a lot of sense; what tells you that we're solving for the median? (this would explain why the distribution is right skewed, since the median is left of the EV).

Comment: *"make the odds in favour of such a thing"* suggests you are looking for the first case where the probability exceeds 50%, so based on the cumulative distribution function and the median

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t understand why something doesn’t work, think of something simpler where you’d also expect it to work and where it would be easier to understand why it doesn’t work.

Consider a five-sided die (made with finest Swiss craftsmanship to have equiprobable faces despite the lack of symmetry). You want to roll a number greater than $2$ (i.e. $3$, $4$ or $5$). How many dice do you need for the odds to be in favour of that? One. How many rolls of one die do you expect to need to get such a number? $\frac1{\frac35}=\frac53$, so the nearest integer is $2$.

It’s hard to explain why something doesn’t work when you haven’t said much about why you think it should work, but this example might help you clarify your thoughts on this. If you still don’t see why it doesn’t work, perhaps it will at least make it easier for you to explain why you think it should work, and that in turn would make it easier for us to explain why it doesn’t.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give an explanatory answer to this question.  Essentially, the reason is that one computation has nothing to do with the other.  If $p_n$ is the probability that it take $n$ rolls for all six faces to appear, then the expected value of the number of rolls required is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty np_n\tag1$$  The number the bartender is looking for is the smallest $N$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^Np_n\geq\frac12\tag2$$

Why should the ceiling say, of the sum in $(1)$ be equal to the $N$ in $(2)$?  No reason, and it isn't.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot. On a Quora post answering this question, the top comment said that we can't use EV exactly because this "distribution is right skewed," so the EV is an overestimate. Do you know what it means by that?

Comment: @JamesFlanagin What it means is that cases where it takes a lot of rolls are counted disproportionately in the expected value calculation.  If $10\%$ of the time it takes $12$ rolls  an $10\%$ of the time it takes $14$, these should contribute equally to the probability, but in the expected value calculation  they contribute $.1\cdot12+.1\cdot14=1.2+1.4$

Comment: Got it. Thank you. :)